# Dumping memory layout of C++ object does not work in clang

Tags: c++, macos, clang, llvm

I have read an article about [dumping a C++ object's memory layout with Clang](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/12/17/dumping-a-c-objects-memory-layout-with-clang/) and now I am trying to play with this feature. I have create two classes:

```
// simple.cpp
struct Base
{
    int value;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    int count;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

and run the following command:

```
$ clang -cc1 -fdump-record-layouts-simple simple.cpp
```

and get nothing. clang version is:

```
$ clang++ -dumpversion
4.2.1
```

If I run the following command:

```
$ clang -cc1 --help
```

and among a lot information I can find this one:

```
...
  -fdump-record-layouts-simple
                          Dump record layout information in a simple form used for testing
  -fdump-record-layouts   Dump record layout information
  -fdump-vtable-layouts   Dump the layouts of all vtables that will be emitted in a translation unit
...
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

1. Add the `-emit-llvm` compiler switch.  Without this, LLVM output is not required, so record layouts are never computed and so not dumped.
2. Use the classes in your code.  If the classes are never used, no code generation is done for them, and their layouts are not dumped.

With these changes made, output like this is printed on stdout:

```
*** Dumping AST Record Layout
Type: struct Base

Layout: <ASTRecordLayout
  Size:32
  DataSize:32
  Alignment:32
  FieldOffsets: [0]>

*** Dumping AST Record Layout
Type: struct Derived

Layout: <ASTRecordLayout
  Size:64
  DataSize:64
  Alignment:32
  FieldOffsets: [32]>
```

...

```
Layout: <CGRecordLayout
  LLVMType:%struct.Base = type { i32 }
  NonVirtualBaseLLVMType:%struct.Base = type { i32 }
  IsZeroInitializable:1
  BitFields:[
]>

Layout: <CGRecordLayout
  LLVMType:%struct.Derived = type { %struct.Base, i32 }
  NonVirtualBaseLLVMType:%struct.Derived = type { %struct.Base, i32 }
  IsZeroInitializable:1
  BitFields:[
]>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an update based on my experiences with clang 10.0.1:

- A necessary condition is that the compiler needs some reason to actually care about the layout of the struct in question. So the `simple.cpp` source file in the original question never seems to result in a dump. I found that adding code to instantiate one of the structs, or calling `sizeof(...)` on it, or calling one of their virtual methods, worked.
- If you're using `-cc1`, then `-emit-llvm` *or* `-emit-obj` is needed to cause the dump. (Maybe other options work as well, but in my experiments I needed at least one of those.)
- If you don't want to use the `-cc1` option (maybe because you want to just add these to an existing build system that assumes g++ compatibility), an invocation like this also works: `clang -Xclang -fdump-record-layouts-simple simple.cpp`. (A bonus to this approach, at least on my system, is that invoking clang in this manner results in the struct layout information being colorized in my terminal.)
- The things I wrote above also seems to also apply to the `-fdump-record-layouts` and `-fdump-vtable-layouts` options.